# Fix date overlap in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataset like this below:

```
+------+------+-------+------------+------------+-----------------+
| key1 | key2 | price | date_start |  date_end  | sequence_number |
+------+------+-------+------------+------------+-----------------+
| a    | b    |    10 | 2022-01-03 | 2022-01-05 |               1 |
| a    | b    |    10 | 2022-01-02 | 2050-05-15 |               2 |
| a    | b    |    10 | 2022-02-02 | 2022-05-10 |               3 |
| a    | b    |    20 | 2024-02-01 | 2050-10-10 |               4 |
| a    | b    |    20 | 2024-04-01 | 2025-09-10 |               5 |
| a    | b    |    10 | 2022-04-02 | 2024-09-10 |               6 |
| a    | b    |    20 | 2024-09-11 | 2050-10-10 |               7 |
+------+------+-------+------------+------------+-----------------+
```

What I want to achieve is this:

```
+------+------+-------+------------+------------+
| key1 | key2 | price | date_start |  date_end  |
+------+------+-------+------------+------------+
| a    | b    |    10 | 2022-01-02 | 2024-09-10 |
| a    | b    |    20 | 2024-09-11 | 2050-10-10 |
+------+------+-------+------------+------------+
```

The sequence number is the order in which the data rows were received.

The resultant dataset should be able to fix the overlapping dates for each price but also consider the fact that when there is a new price for the same key columns the older record's date_end is updated to date_start-1

After the first three sequence numbers, the output looked like this:

```
+------+------+-------+------------+------------+
| key1 | key2 | price | date_start |  date_end  |
+------+------+-------+------------+------------+
| a    | b    |    10 | 2022-01-02 | 2050-05-15 |
+------+------+-------+------------+------------+
```

This covers the max range for the price.

After the 4th sequence number:

```
+------+------+-------+------------+------------+
| key1 | key2 | price | date_start |  date_end  |
+------+------+-------+------------+------------+
| a    | b    |    10 | 2022-01-02 | 2024-01-31 |
| a    | b    |    20 | 2024-02-01 | 2050-10-10 |
+------+------+-------+------------+------------+
```

After the 5th sequence number:

```
+------+------+-------+------------+------------+
| key1 | key2 | price | date_start |  date_end  |
+------+------+-------+------------+------------+
| a    | b    |    10 | 2022-01-02 | 2024-01-31 |
| a    | b    |    20 | 2024-02-01 | 2050-10-10 |
+------+------+-------+------------+------------+
```

No changes as the date overlaps

After the 6th sequence number:

```
+------+------+-------+------------+------------+
| key1 | key2 | price | date_start |  date_end  |
+------+------+-------+------------+------------+
| a    | b    |    10 | 2022-01-02 | 2024-09-10 |
| a    | b    |    20 | 2024-09-11 | 2050-10-10 |
+------+------+-------+------------+------------+
```

The date_start and date_end both are updated

After the 7th sequence number:

```
+------+------+-------+------------+------------+
| key1 | key2 | price | date_start |  date_end  |
+------+------+-------+------------+------------+
| a    | b    |    10 | 2022-01-02 | 2024-09-10 |
| a    | b    |    20 | 2024-09-11 | 2050-10-10 |
+------+------+-------+------------+------------+
```

No changes.

Comment: Your 6th and 7th rows and data update rules don't match. The data has different dates.

Comment: after 6th, which is  - ```10 | 2022-04-02 | 2024-09-10``` . 

This date_start > older date_start i.e within the range so no changes
This date_end > older date_end i.e outside the range so updated to new date_end
Hence we also update the date_start of row 20 as it will overlap because of the above change.

no changes after 7th as they fall under the range.

I don't understand your comment.

Comment: What happens when you have 3 or more prices? Is it possible that 2 consecutive prices (intervals) do not overlap? Can the same price reappear at a later time, e.g., 10 from t1-t2, 20 from t2-t3 and 10 again from t3-t4? Does "new price" refer to changed price from the previous row, or to a not yet seen number?

Comment: Do you need a solution that can process the whole dataframe every time, or update the old dataframe when the new row data comes in?

Comment: @bzu yes to all your questions

Comment: @JonathanLam whole dataframe at once

Answer (score 0):

So here's an answer.  First I expand the dates into rows. Then I use a group by with struct & collect_list, to capture the price and sequence_number together.  I take the first item of the array returned (and sorted) from collect list to effectively give me the max of the sequence number to then pull back the price.  From there a group the dates by min/max.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import min, explode, col, expr, max
data = [

("a"    ,"b"    ,   10 ,"2022-01-03" ,"2022-01-05" ,              1 ),
("a"    ,"b"    ,   10 ,"2022-01-02" ,"2050-05-15" ,              2 ),
("a"    ,"b"    ,   10 ,"2022-02-02" ,"2022-05-10" ,              3 ),
("a"    ,"b"    ,   20 ,"2024-02-01" ,"2050-10-10" ,              4 ),
("a"    ,"b"    ,   20 ,"2024-04-01" ,"2025-09-10" ,              5 ),
("a"    ,"b"    ,   10 ,"2022-04-02" ,"2024-09-10" ,              6 ),
("a"    ,"b"    ,   20 ,"2024-09-11" ,"2050-10-10" ,              7 ),
]
columns = ["key1","key2","price","date_start","date_end","sequence_number"]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(*columns)

#create all the dates as rows 
df_sequence = df.select( "*" , explode( expr("sequence ( to_date(date_start),to_date(date_end), interval 1 day)").alias('day') ) )

df_date_range = df_sequence.groupby( \
 col("key1"),
 col("key2"), 
 col("col") 
).agg( \# here's the magic
 reverse( \#descending sort effectively on sequence number.
  array_sort( \#ascending sort of array by first element in struct then second element in struct
   collect_list( \# collect all elements of the group
    struct( \# get all data we need 
     col("sequence_number").alias("sequence") ,
     col("price" ).alias("price") 
    ) 
   )
  )
 )[0].alias("mystruct")\ # pull the first element to get "max"
).select( \
 col("key1"), 
 col("key2"), 
 col("col"), 
 col("mystruct.price") \#pull out price from struct
)
#without comments
#df_date_range = df_sequence.groupby( col("key1"),col("key2"), col("col") ).agg( reverse(array_sort(collect_list( struct(col("sequence_number").alias("sequence") ,col("price" ).alias("price") ) )))[0].alias("mystruct") ).select( col("key1"), col("key2"), col("col"), col("mystruct.price") )

df_date_range.groupby(  col("key1"),col("key2"), col("price") ).agg( min("col").alias("date_start"), max("col").alias("date_end") ).show()
+----+----+-----+----------+----------+                                         
|key1|key2|price|  date_start |  date_end|
+----+----+-----+----------+----------+
|   a|   b|   10|2022-01-02|2024-09-10|
|   a|   b|   20|2024-09-11|2050-10-10|
+----+----+-----+----------+----------+
```

This does assume you will only ever use the price once before changing it.  If you needed to go to back to a price you'd have to use window logic to identify the price different prices ranges and add that to your collect_list as an extra factor to sort on.